# How do I query the OData/REST API in 2013 effectively using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, rest, odata

I want to use the improved OData/REST API in Sharepoint 2013 but it's hard to find good examples. As I see it, the OData-endpoint is of little use without a dedicated OData client library. With plain jQuery there's so much boilerplate I'd might as well just use JSOM and CAML.

So far I've found data.js, a low level library and [JayData](http://jaydata.org/) and [Breeze.js](http://www.breezejs.com/), both depend on data.js. I have yet to find any code samples with any of these libraries being used in the context of Sharepoint.

Does anyone else have any know how on the subject?

Answer (score 2):

This article on MSDN shows some examples of using jQuery.ajax calls:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj164022.aspx

Here is a good blog as well:

http://blog.concentra.co.uk/2013/02/06/odata/

The only gotcha at all with calling the SharePoint 2013 REST API is that if you are doing anything other than GET, you have to add the custom X-RequestDigest header for security, and the If-Match for concurrency checking. Both are covered in the blog article.